# Xamarin Realm no realmobject has linker stripped them

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, realm, portable-class-library

I am receiving an exception at runtime as follows.

"No realmobject.  Has linker stripped them...."

My solution includes a PCL, Android and IOS project with Visual studio Mac and the realm package 1.6.0 installed in each project. I've also checked that Fodyweaver.xml includes the correct  reference and all packages have th same version.

When I have the PCL included in the same folder as the solution (i.e like the default multiplatform solution with PCL) everything works ok.

However I moved the PCL project which includes all the realm logic to a separate folder so I can use it across multiple solutions.  My solution now includes the PCL from this external folder and the iOS and Android project also reference the realm packages.  the app compiles fine but when I run the application it now receives this exception on the first call to use realm.getinstance.

If Input the PCL project back into the same folder as the main solution as originally created it works fine.

can anyone advise a fix for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue now.  Firstly I had applied the solution from @sushhangover,  but it didn't work straight off.

After some investigation I discovered the compiler was not weaving the classes  and realm objects into the library at all.

I simply loaded the library independently of my main solution, removed and reloaded realm packages and Fody, cleaned it all, rebuild All.  and then I could see the fodyweaver working properly.  I then added the reference back into my main solution and it all works .

Comment: I am getting same error when I copy db file with `WriteCopyTo` and share it via intent and download and try to restore . Using decryption with same key though.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same *issue* I have when placing my `RealmObject` models into a separate library (PCL or NetStd) as I use a `Viper` architecture and I share the same model across multiple solutions.

When Realms.Realm.GetInstance(....) is called the Realm initialization assumes the `RealmObject`s will be in the same assembly or that the assembly containing is already loaded, but they are not in this case. You can tell this is the case as a compiler ***warning is issued in the assembly build*** (via the `Fody` processing) that is calling `GetInstance` but that does not have any RealmObjects in it:

> Warning: Fody/RealmWeaver: Default schema appears to be empty. This is not an error if you don't have any RealmObject inheritors declared. Otherwise it may be a bug with the weaver. (GeneticCancerSelectors)

So I add a static class to my Realm model library:

```
public static class RealmModel
{
    public static Realms.Realm GetInstance() => GetInstance("");

    public static Realms.Realm GetInstance(string databasePath) => GetInstance(new RealmConfiguration(databasePath));

    public static Realms.Realm GetInstance(RealmConfigurationBase config = null) => Realms.Realm.GetInstance(config);

    public static Task<Realms.Realm> GetInstanceAsync(RealmConfigurationBase config) => Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync(config);
}
```

Now when you need to get a Realm instance, do not call:

```
Realms.Realm.GetInstance()
```

But call the one in your Model assembly:

```
RealmModel.GetInstance()
```

Comment: To clarify why this works - the weaver will inject registration code in the module initializer of the PCL/NetStandard lib that will let Realm know about its models. The problem manifests itself if Realm is used before the library has been loaded - the cctor isn't run, so models from the library haven't been registered. With the proposed code change, you make sure that you're accessing the library before getting an instance, so it'll work. Alternatively, you can add a dummy `Init()` method in your library and call that upon app launch to eagerly load it and invoke the cctor.

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev Thanks for the additional information, I should have added something about doing a dummy initializer. My repository setups always grabs the GetInstance from my Realm model so no one has to remember to "pre-initialize" it, this also avoids getting the Fody/RealmWeaver compiler warning since there is nothing to weave in the other assembly.

Comment: I'm also using VIPER:).  makes sense - but I've tried it and it doesn't work for my solution.  I have a class called DataService which I added the static Getinstance() methods on.    Dataservice is being initialised using dependency injection using the  ninject library  -  so when the dataservice instance is initialised by ninject the constructor is called and this is where I call the static Getinstance - but he exception still occurs.  I tried using a dummy intialiser on Datservice,  but it still fails

Comment: I can add that if I try directly too call DataService.GetInstance() from the PCL from my appdelegate in the iOS project  I get the same error

Comment: @ChrisBaxter I am not using any 3rd-party DI (but do not see how that would related). I have a "model" solution/project that is outside of other solutions that includes the  RealmObjects model project and do not get that error on my iOS or Android apps. Are these Forms-based applications?

Comment: @SushiHangover - It not forms - its a native iOS/android project.  I agree from testing that DI is not the cause.  My setup appears to be the same with the PCL in a separate solution/project then references added to the parent solution. Do you think there are some build /compiler settings I may need to adjust ?  DO you have a working  example I can compare to?

Comment: @ChrisBaxter Strange... None of mine are Form's based either, well I do have a DevOps Dashboard that uses Viper and Realm, if is was a Form's based iOS app, then calling a dummy static initializer (from the model) in the native app before the Form's app init solves the realm lazy load... I'll see if I can put together an example... Are you getting *any* `Default schema appears to be empty` warnings in any of your solution's projects?

Comment: I'm not getting any schema warnings.  I have however managed to Create a separate test project using an external PCL with the realm model as you suggested and that works.  BUT,  with my main project I still get the error. Beyond the fact that my main project has a lot of other files and realm objects in it I can't see the difference so still confused whats causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks to Chris Baxter.

That's my situation.

- [WPF Application, Fody 3.0.3, Realm 3.4.0]
- Exception: No RealmObjects. Has linker stripped them?

---

...This is my First Time using Realm, and It's really bad feeling...

1. A [Brand New] Blank WPF Project
2. Nuget => Realm
3. Required FodyWeavers.xml file Created in Solution Folder, because Nuget can't
   do this for you now.
4. (Somehow I Update Then Downgrade a latest version of Fody, after
   recongized that Realm don't support Any Fody which version newer
   than 3.X)
5. Awful Exception Occurs, ooooops!
6. (hours work with System
   Auth, SpecialFolder, etc... Until I Discovered Chris Baxter's
   answer)

Xml file content:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
<RealmWeaver/>
</Weavers>
```

---

How to Solve the Problem:
Just Clean And ReBuild Solution, Problem Solved.

Comment: I am confused by this solution. What do you mean by 'Just Clean And ReGenerate Solution'? Can you clarify what you have added to the accepted solution?